# How to call Jekyll commands from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I have a Rails app which creates/builds some Jekyll sites on the same server. Right now, I'm calling Jekyll commands with backticks like this:

```
def build_jekyll
  result = `jekyll build -s /some/source/path -d /some/dest/path`
end
```

This works fine but feels a little un-ruby like. If the jekyll gem is in my Rails Gemfile, **is there a way I can build a jekyll site using ruby?**

*(from the docs, it looks like I would call `Jekyll::Commands::Build.build` but I'm not sure how to initialize the site parameter).*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
require 'jekyll'

conf = Jekyll.configuration({
  'source'      => 'path/to/source',
  'destination' => 'path/to/destination'
})

Jekyll::Site.new(conf).process
```

## But how did you find out?

I figured this out by looking at [the source code](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). When you run `jekyll build`, you enter into the source file [`bin/jekyll`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/bin/jekyll#L71-L72). The interesting part here is

```
command :build do |c|
  # ommitted

  c.action do |args, options|
    options = normalize_options(options.__hash__)
    options = Jekyll.configuration(options)
    Jekyll::Commands::Build.process(options)
  end
end
```

Hm, looks like the actual work is done in `Jekyll::Commands::Build.process`, so let's take a look into that method in [`lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb#L4-L9):

```
def self.process(options)
  site = Jekyll::Site.new(options)
  self.build(site, options)

  # other stuff
end
```

Again, the actual magic happens somewhere else, namely in `Jekyll::Commands::Build.build`, also in [`lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb#L17-L25)

```
def self.build(site, options)
  # some logging going on here

  self.process_site(site)
end
```

This in turn calls a class method called `process_site`, which comes from the superclass `Jekyll::Command` defined in [`lib/jekyll/command.rb`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/command.rb#L17-L25)

```
def self.process_site(site)
  site.process
rescue Jekyll::FatalException => e
  # some error handling
end
```

So we actually want to call `process` on a `Jekyll::Site`. One thing we have yet to find out is how to specify options for the `Jekyll::Site` instance. Let's take a closer look at [`lib/jekyll/site.rb`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/site.rb#L19-L20)

```
def initialize(config)
  # more options ...

  self.source          = File.expand_path(config['source'])
  self.dest            = File.expand_path(config['destination'])

  # more options ...
end
```

So apparently we need to supply a hash with the `'source'` and `'destination'` keys pointing to the desired directories. The rest of the configuration will be generated by Jekyll with the `Jekyll.configuration` method which we saw earlier in `bin/jekyll`. That's about it. Now, the only thing left to do is putting the pieces together ;-)

Comment: The docs don't list the method Jekyll::Site.new.  Where did you find that?

Comment: In the source ;-) https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb#L5

Comment: I see the call to that method, however there isn't a new() method defined in the source code for the class Jekyll::Site:  https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/site.rb

Comment: I was in the mood so i wrote up how i stepped through the code :)

Comment: You normally define the `initialize` method in Ruby in order to define a constructor. The `new` method will call this internally. There are only very rare cases where one needs to overwrite the existing `new` method inherited from the `Object` class.

Comment: `You normally define the initialize method in Ruby in order to define a constructor`  Whoops.  Thanks.

Comment: I think `sh "jekyll build"` is more reliable because Jekyll's code can change... I had problem with `Jekyll::Commands::Build.process(options)` and previous line until I changed to `sh "jekyll build"` (in my plugin, `site.config['destination']` gave me the same as the source one...)

Answer (score 0):

Updating this because it looks like the syntax changed, this works now

```rb
require "jekyll"

options = {
    "source"      => './',
    "destination" => './_site',
    "watch" => true,
    "verbose" => true
  }

Jekyll::Commands::Build.process(options)
```